# Need to create a data table column string from data in another column

Tags: r

I am trying to create a column that uses data from another column in the data table and puts it into a string.  For example, I have column amt with values 16, 24, 47, and 32.  I then use floor(d$amt/10)*10 to get the result of 10, 20, 40, and 30.  The column I want to create would be a column of strings "10-19%', "20-29%", etc..

Basically I would want to use

```
cat(floor(d$amt/10)*10, '-', floor(d$amt/10)*10+9, '%', sep="")
```

but this doesn't give a new column.

I tried putting the values in a temporary array and making another array using a for loop, but I keep getting the error that replacement has length 0.

```
temp = floor(d_1990$amt/10)*10
ret = rep(0, 267)
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
print(i)
x = temp[i]
ret[i] = cat(x, '-', x+10, '%', sep="")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cut` or `Hmisc::cut2()` is definitely the way to go here, but you can also approach this your approach via:

```
df <- data.frame(amt = c(16, 24, 47, 32))    
df$label <- paste0(floor(df$amt / 10) * 10, "-", floor(df$amt / 10) * 10 + 9, "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut()` to identify the breakpoints you want, and use the `labels` argument to identify the strings you want it to output.

```
data <- data.frame(amt = c(16, 24, 47, 32))
data$grp <- cut(data$amt,
                breaks = seq(0,100,10),
                right = FALSE,
                labels = c("0-10%", "11-20%", "21-30%", "31-40%", "41-50%", "51-60%", "61-70%", "71-80%", "81-90%", "91-100%"))
```